# Bootstrap carousel next and prev function not working, only first image shows up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

The carousel only displays the first image. It will not slide from one picture to the next.
Here is my code:

```
<body>
</nav>
<div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active"><img src="../Images/BhutanBoys.png"  

  alt="First slide image" class="center-block">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>First slide Heading</h3>
      <p>First slide Caption</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img src="../Images/Bhutan.png" alt="Second slide 

  image" class="center-block">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Second slide Heading</h3>
      <p>Second slide Caption</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img src="../Images/bicycleboy.png" alt="Third slide 

  image" class="center-block">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Third slide Heading</h3>
      <p>Third slide Caption</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel1" role="button"  

  data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"    

  aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a><a 

  class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel1" role="button" 

  data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" 

  aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a></div>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have looked and i cannot find the issue for ages. i have tried to use other answers but they did not work. please help, thanks.

Comment: You may want to load your javascript files in the <head> as well as the bootstrap .css files. After which, check your browser's development tools (usually F12) to see if there are any 404's in the network traffic tab. If you find a 404 in the network tab for one of the bootstrap files, it indicates it's not loading properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code it seems like you have unclosed `<div>` tags.

Are you loading the bootstrap Css in the `<head>` tag?